# Is there a variable that contains the current row for filtering a subset in R?

Tags: r, subset, readr

I want to filter a large dataframe that contains a latitude and longitude. I want to use the method `distHaversine()`, which generates the distance between two points by latitude and longitude. With that, I want to filter out measurements that are far away from a city.
The method expects 2 vectors, one reference point and one specific point, containing 2 values each(lat, lon).

Is there a generic variable I can choose to just take lat, lon from my dataframe, like `distHaversine(c(8.682127, 50.110922), c([i,lat], [i,lon]))`?

My workaround is to just filter by concrete values of latitude and longitude.
Thanks for help :)

Using lat and lon will lead to an error, since the method will calculate the distance for one point, not for a whole set. So I need to always take one value at once for this function.

Evaluation error: Wrong length for a vector, should be 2.

```
library(geosphere)   
library(readr)


ff <- function(x, pos)  subset(x, distHaversine(c(8.682127, 50.110922), c(lat, lon))<60000,    select= c(lat, lon, timestamp, value ))


yy <- readr::read_csv2_chunked("data.csv", DataFrameCallback$new(ff), 
    chunk_size = 100000, col_names = TRUE)
```

edit: for some reason, lat and long are integer, no double values. I noted that and divided by 1000 for calculations

```
    dput(head(yy, 20))
structure(list(lat = c(52023, 42139, 43762, 52023, 54644, 52023, 
52023, 51278, -32879, 52023, 51434, 52023, 42139, 43762, 52023, 
52023, 52023, -32879, 52023, 52023), lon = c(4692, 24794, -79185, 
4692, 9760, 4692, 4692, 12588, -68877, 4692, 6115, 4692, 24794, 
-79185, 4692, 4692, 4692, -68877, 4692, 4692), timestamp =    structure(c(1538352021, 
1538352035, 1538352044, 1538352050, 1538352061, 1538352080, 1538352110, 
1538352110, 1538352132, 1538352140, 1538352147, 1538352170, 1538352183, 
1538352192, 1538352200, 1538352230, 1538352260, 1538352283, 1538352290, 
1538352320), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    P1 = c("1.2", "10.80", "3.00", "1.7", "12.3", "2.0", "1.0", 
    "4.75", "1.00", "1.0", "19.3", "1.8", "11.60", "4.00", "1.0", 
    "0.8", "1.0", "2.00", "1.1", "1.3")), .Names = c("lat", "lon", 
"timestamp", "P1"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The result shall be a filtered dataframe

```
lat     lon     timestamp    P1        
9,5     50,5     1.1.2019    123    
8,8     49,3     1.1.2019    23     
...
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(yy)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(yy, 20))`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and wrote a tidyverse-friendly wrapper for geosphere's `distGeo`. Geodesic distance is quite a bit more accurate than haversine, but the same is certainly possible also with `distHaversine`.

#### Data

```
library(geosphere)
library(tidyverse)
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RomanAbashin/distGeo_v/master/distGeo_v.R")

df <- tibble(lon = rnorm(1000, 16.3738, sd = 1),
             lat = rnorm(1000, 48.2082, sd = 1),
             cx = 16.3738,
             cy = 48.2082)
```

#### Code

```
df %>%
    filter(distGeo_v(lon, lat, cx, cy) < 10000)
```

#### Result

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
    lon   lat    cx    cy
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  16.5  48.2  16.4  48.2
2  16.3  48.2  16.4  48.2
3  16.4  48.3  16.4  48.2
4  16.3  48.2  16.4  48.2
5  16.3  48.2  16.4  48.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse approach that uses the `pmap_df` function to run `distHaversine` on each pair of lat/lon coordinates and return a data frame with the results. You can then filter the output for points that are within some distance from each other.

```
library(geosphere)   
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data
set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(lon=runif(5,-180,180), lat = runif(5,-90,90))

dist = pmap_df(data.frame(t(combn(1:nrow(dat), 2))), 
               ~data.frame(dat[.x, ] %>% set_names(c("lon1","lat1")), 
                           dat[.y, ] %>% set_names(c("lon2", "lat2")), 
                           dist=distHaversine(dat[.x, ], dat[.y, ])))

dist
```

> ```
>          lon1       lat1       lon2       lat2     dist
> 1  -113.44239  79.825493   72.85465 -66.751384 18570291
> 2  -113.44239  79.825493   26.39748  60.020787  4259930
> 3  -113.44239  79.825493 -119.50131  -5.756667  9533243
> 4  -113.44239  79.825493  159.78216   8.997074  8969682
> 5    72.85465 -66.751384   26.39748  60.020787 14616198
> 6    72.85465 -66.751384 -119.50131  -5.756667 11905205
> 7    72.85465 -66.751384  159.78216   8.997074 10803902
> 8    26.39748  60.020787 -119.50131  -5.756667 13347748
> 9    26.39748  60.020787  159.78216   8.997074 11326140
> 10 -119.50131  -5.756667  159.78216   8.997074  9104543
> ```

If you just want a quick way to get distances between a given lat/lon coordinate (to make things concrete, let's say the coordinates in the second row of the data frame) and all the other coordinates, here's an approach using the base R `apply` function:

```
apply(dat[-2, ], 1, function(ll) distHaversine(dat[2,], ll))
```

> ```
>        1        3        4        5 
> 18570291 14616198 11905205 10803902
> ```